Calling `getLendingPool` in a function call `getLendingPool`
The ILendingPoolAddressProvider does not contain the getLendingPool function.
async function getLendingPool(account) {
  const lendingPoolAddressProvider = await ethers.getContractAt(
    "ILendingPoolAddressesProvider", // This is the interface
    "0xB53C1a33016B2DC2fF3653530bfF1848a515c8c5",
    account,
  )
  const lendingPoolAddress = await lendingPoolAddressProvider.getLendingPool()
  const lendingPool = await ethers.getContractAt(
    "ILendingPoool",
    lendingPoolAddress,
    account,
  )
  return lendingPool
}


You’ve to use the contract name instead of the interface name. Please share more details and relevant code.

https://github.com/EddiePumpin/Hardhat-DeFi
Sorry for the late response

The following things need to be changed (mostly in aaveBorrow.js script):

Change ethers import from ethers to hardhat package (as getContractAt is a function of ethers imported from hardhat).
Uninstalled the ethers package to avoid version conflicts.
Replaced { deployer } to [ deployer ] in the lvalue (or LHS) of await ethers.getSigners().
In the borrow and repay function calls of lendingPool, changed the argument value of 1 (i.e., denoting the interestRateMode and rateMode in the borrow and repay functions respectively) to 2.  For this, you can refer to the explanation in this post.

Console output of yarn hardhat run scripts/aaveBorrow.js:

PS. I've done all these changes and created a PR. You can review it and merge it into your repository.

What is the reason for this "Replaced { deployer } to [ deployer ] in the lvalue (or LHS) of await ethers.getSigners()."

And thanks for always helping me

After runing yarn hardhat run scripts/aaveBorrow.js I got this TypeError: ethers.parseEther is not a function     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP FOLIO\.vscode\hardhat-defi-fcc\scripts\getWeth.js:3:23)

You’re welcome, @EddiePumpin. Happy to help!

The reason for replacing { deployer } with [ deployer ] is await getSigners() returns the array of signer objects.

You need to refer to the fixes branch of my forked repo, instead of the main branch. In that, it’s ethers.utils.parseEther. I’ve created the PR using the fixes branch only.

You can just simply click on Merge Pull Request and then execute git pull in your repo’s codebase itself. It’ll reflect the mentioned changes in your repo automatically.

What is the best way to message you? I meant which social media? I can't message you on X because I don't have blue tick

I've just seen your follow, and followed you back. So, hopefully, you can message me now there.
